# Run-time Error '1004' The file could not be accessed in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I've been given an Excel 2016 spreadsheet which I don't own and do not maintain. A macro is mapped to a button, which passes a filename such as *.\input\common\datafile.txt*.

The spreadsheet ships with the datafile.txt file in the input\common\ subdirectory below the spreadsheet root directory.

When other members of the team execute the macro in the spreadsheet, the datafile.txt file loads without problem. On my PC, the macro halts with run time error 1004, saying that the file cannot be accessed.

The macro looks like this:

```
Sub Load_Input_File(file_location As String)

' Commented out other code'

Workbooks.OpenText filename:=file_location, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

and the debugger shows that file_location is "*.\input\common\datafile.txt*". If I change file_location to be "*D:\Temp\input\common\datafile.txt*", the macro runs correctly.

For all other users, the macro runs as is. On my system, which is the same standard laptop (Windows 10, Excel 2016) as my teammates, the relative path fails.

Since I don't own the spreadsheet or the macro, changing the code is not an option. Can anyone think of any environmental reason why Excel reports not finding a file based on a relative pathname? It's almost as if it's thinking it's running from a different location or something.

I'm neither an Excel guru nor a VBA wizard. This was provided by another group as a "it just works" solution that has in fact run for everyone but me. I supposedly have the same installation of Office and etc. as my team mates. I don't see any privilege or permission differences between our accounts.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `.` represents the current directory - that may or may not be the folder containing the workbook, depending on when and how the workbook was opened, and what you've done since then.  A more robust approach would be to use `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\input\common\datafile.txt"`    When it fails if you type `? CurDir` into the Immediate pane and hit Enter, what do you see?

Comment: ...if you can't make any changes then it should work if you start Excel, then use File > Open and navigate to the folder with the macro, then run the macro

Comment: @Tim, the File > Open > Browse shows the same directory as the spreadsheet itself (say D:\Temp), and the D:\Temp\input\common\datafile.txt exists, and is readable.

Comment: If that's the case then I don't know what the issue might be.  Is there some permissions problem?

Comment: I've been playing around with it, and I think I've found the what, but not the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Williams wrote in the comments, your issue is that `.\input\common\datafile.txt` points to the so called *current working directory* (cwd). This cwd can change at any time, so it's not a very clever idea to use this as path in the code. Note that the cwd is valid for the whole Excel session (including VBA), not only one workbook. You can check the cwd in VBA with the command `CurDir`.

Anyhow, as you stated that you can't change the code, you need to change the cwd so that points to the folder where the Excel with the macro is (or, more precise, where the `Input`-subfolder is located.

You can change the cwd by opening the File Browser Dialog: In Excel, use `File->Open` and click `Browse`. Now navigate to the folder. If your Excel Workbook with the data is not already open, you can open it from here, if it is already open, just press Cancel.

Alternative is to use the `ChDir`-command in VBA. You could create a small macro in your Personal file and maybe assign a keyboard shortcut to it (if you don't have a Personal workbook yet, see the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566)).

```
Sub openTheMagicMacroFile()
    Const Path = "C:\Users\FunThomas\Documents\TestVBA"
    Const Filename = "LoadInput.xlsm"
    
    ChDrive left(path, 2)
    ChDir Path
    Workbooks.Open Path & "\" & Filename
End Sub
```

Just adapt the `Path` and `Filename` to your needs. If you want, you can also add a call to the macro within the workbook (use the [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run) command)

**Update** Thanks to the hint of Tim Williams: You will need to issue a `ChDrive` to set the drive first. In the background, there is a kind of cwd for every drive, so if you issue the chDir command for a different drive, the cwd of that drive changed, but the *real* cwd remains untouched. Code adapted.

Comment: Note - need to call `ChDrive` first if the current directory is not on the drive with the desired target for `ChDir`

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks for the hint, completely forgot about that. Updated the answer.

Comment: I think that's the issue. Looking in the macro code, I see that there is a "ChDir ActiveWorkbook.path" call prior to the WorkBooks.OpenText call. I have been using my data drive (D:) since my system drive (C:) is out of space. It looks like even though the spreadsheet is in D:\Temp, Excel is looking at %USERPROFILE%\Documents, which is the C: drive, and the chdir isn't changing the drive. Thanks; I'll let the spreadsheet author know.

Comment: Good find!  Hopefully the author can fix their code and make it little more robust.